# Is it ever safe to use a non-stick pan under the broiler (e.g. frittatas)?

Tags: equipment, kitchen-safety, non-stick, frittata

I see a lot of frittata recipes call for using a non-stick pan, and for finishing under the broiler (or "grill" in UK-speak). However, I have also read that non-stick pans in general are not broiler-safe. Can anyone clarify the science on this? Are recipe-writers just giving people really bad advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary: it's kinda-sorta bad advice, but not terrible

Teflon starts to [degrade at 260C (500F)](https://www.teflon.com/en/consumers/teflon-coatings-cookware-bakeware/safety), which is why authorities recommend against broiling, where items directly under the broiling element can get above that temperature.

Frittatas, like Spanish tortillas and a few other dishes, have some conditions that can ameliorate this, however:

- Generally you only broil the frittata for [a couple of minutes](https://www.eatlivetravelwrite.com/2018/03/frittata-with-spring-greens-and-potatoes/)
- The pan is mostly full of frittata, which means that only the edge is directly exposed to radiant heat
- Many recipes call for [broiling on low](https://www.eatlivetravelwrite.com/2018/03/frittata-with-spring-greens-and-potatoes/) instead of high

That said, though, if you made frittatas frequently in a nonstick pan, and finished them under a hot broiler every time, I would expect your nonstick pan to start losing its coating around the edges.  It's not something I would do, particularly since there are so many alternatives do cooking one this way:

- Use a [cast-iron pan](https://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-make-a-frittata-cooking-lessons-from-the-kitchn-170717)
- [Bake it](https://cookieandkate.com/best-frittata-recipe/) in a moderate to warm oven
- [Flip the frittata](https://www.bonappetit.com/story/how-to-make-a-frittata-stovetop) and don't use the oven at all

Comment: Flip the frittata! Sacrilege!

Comment: I'd also doubt that the handles of cheaper non-stick pans could cope with these temperatures. Built to a price, little point putting heat-resistant handles on a product if the coating isn't either.